# iterate over pandas dataframe and update the value - AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate over a pandas dataframe and update the value if condition is met but i am getting an error.

```
for line, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 1):
    if row.Qty:
        if row.Qty == 1 and row.Price == 10:
            row.Buy = 1
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First iterating in pandas is possible, but very slow, so another vectorized solution are used.

I think you can use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) if you need iterating:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if  df.loc[idx,'Qty'] == 1 and df.loc[idx,'Price'] == 10:
        df.loc[idx,'Buy'] = 1
```

But better is to use vectorized solutions – set value by boolean mask with `loc`:

```
mask = (df['Qty'] == 1) & (df['Price'] == 10)
df.loc[mask, 'Buy'] = 1
```

Or solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Buy'] = df['Buy'].mask(mask, 1)
```

Or if you need `if...else` use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Buy'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
```

**Samples**.

Set values by conditions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Buy': [100, 200, 50], 
                   'Qty': [5, 1, 1], 
                   'Name': ['apple', 'pear', 'banana'], 
                   'Price': [1, 10, 10]})

print (df)
   Buy    Name  Price  Qty
0  100   apple      1    5
1  200    pear     10    1
2   50  banana     10    1
```

---

```
mask = (df['Qty'] == 1) & (df['Price'] == 10)


df['Buy'] = df['Buy'].mask(mask, 1)
print (df)
   Buy    Name  Price  Qty
0  100   apple      1    5
1    1    pear     10    1
2    1  banana     10    1
```

```
df['Buy'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
print (df)
   Buy    Name  Price  Qty
0    0   apple      1    5
1    1    pear     10    1
2    1  banana     10    1
```

Answer (score 21):

Ok, if you intend to set values in `df` then you need track the `index` values.

***option 1***
using `itertuples`

```
# keep in mind `row` is a named tuple and cannot be edited
for line, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 1):  # you don't need enumerate here, but doesn't hurt.
    if row.Qty:
        if row.Qty == 1 and row.Price == 10:
            df.set_value(row.Index, 'Buy', 1)
```

***option 2***
using `iterrows`

```
# keep in mind that `row` is a `pd.Series` and can be edited...
# ... but it is just a copy and won't reflect in `df`
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Qty:
        if row.Qty == 1 and row.Price == 10:
            df.set_value(idx, 'Buy', 1)
```

***option 3***
using straight up loop with `get_value`

```
for idx in df.index:
    q = df.get_value(idx, 'Qty')
    if q:
        p = df.get_value(idx, 'Price')
        if q == 1 and p == 10:
            df.set_value(idx, 'Buy', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply piRSquared. Can we do inplace replace using itertuples or iterrows?

Comment: `itertuples`.. No!  `tuples` are immutable...meaning they cannot be changed.  `iterrows`... No?  `pd.Series` can definitely be changed.  But `row` is only a copy of the row in the `df`.  I'll add one more looping option.  However, `pandas` if far more effective with its vectorized operations as @jezrael points out.

Comment: you could still use itertuples. index 0 gives the index of the dataframe, so you could simply use that to insert the value by doing something like  i = row[0]   followed by df.loc[i, 'column_name'] = some_value

Comment: Your comment states that Enumerate is not needed there?  But isn't enumerate needed to get the index (eg the index in the data-frame could skip numbers or not be even a number)

Comment: fyi..submitted edits to replace `set_value`. It has been deprecated in favor of `at` or `iat`.

Answer (score 16):

pandas.DataFrame.set_value method is deprecated as of 0.21.0 [pd.DataFrame.set_value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html)

Use [pandas.Dataframe.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.Qty and row.Qty == 1 and row.Price == 10:
            df.at[index,'Buy'] = 1
```

Comment: from the docs: `You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.`

Comment: @techkuz correct, but this example does not modify the iterating object's value —rather the original data frame.